# Visual Studio 2013 Express multiple projects

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, visual-studio

Now when the Visual Studio 2013 Express separated into different Editions for web, desktop and so on, I have a problem. For example my solution consists of two projects WPF and WCF I can't fully load solution, because for web Edition opens WCF and desktop Edition opens WPF. Is there any ways how to solve this problem, o I'll have intall VS 2012 Express?

Comment: I haven't used an express edition since 2010, but I'm pretty sure you can't have projects from different editions (web, desktop, etc) in one solution.  You probably need the full version of Visual Studio.

Comment: so there's no workaround?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Doesn't mean there isn't one, but I doubt there is.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio Express has always been limited in this manner.

The different editions can only open certain types of projects, and if you have a solution that consists of projects that will only open in different editions of Visual Studio you will need to build each on a different instance.

However, recently Microsoft released [Visual Studio Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs), which doesn't have this limitation - it too is free, like the Express editions.